# SavedModel file does not exist at: path

Tags: python, tensorflow, flask, python-imaging-library

I created an image recognition model with teachable machine. The model worked great before I had to switch computer. Now it is no longer working and I get the error SavedModel file does not exist at:

`

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, flash
import tensorflow.keras
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('gallery.db')
c = conn.cursor()

conn.commit()
c.close()
conn.close()

app = Flask(__name__)
uFolder = 'static'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}
model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('../model/keras_model.h5', compile=False)


def classify(img_path):
    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
    data = np.ndarray(shape=(1, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    image = Image.open(img_path)
    size = (224, 224)
    image = ImageOps.fit(image, size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_array = np.asarray(image)
    normalized_image_array = (img_array.astype(np.float32) / 127.0) - 1
    data[0] = normalized_image_array
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    classLabels = ["Al4C", "Al4CS", "AlGui", "AlGbla", "Not"]
    return (classLabels[np.argmax(prediction)])
```

`

Comment: That image tells us nothing.  We need to see the code, pasted as text.  Did your directory structure change on the new machine?  Are you using an absolute path?  Does the file actually exist?

Comment: When changing machine I sent the files zip file on google. ops. So it could have changed. I entered the absolute path and got more errors. I don't know if the file is corrupted.

Comment: Absolute paths are almost always a bad idea, for exactly this reason.  The "../model/keras_model.h5" is good, assuming the file actually exists there.  For debugging, you should `print(os.getcwd())` and maybe `print(os.listdir("../model"))` just to confirm where you are and what's present.

Comment: I gave print(os.getcwd()) a try and the code stops after "model = tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('../model/keras_model.h5', compile=False)"

Comment: and it prints nothing for print(os.listdir("../model"))

Comment: Well, that tells you that the file is not where you think it is.  Now you need to figure out what happened to it.